# Best List view solution for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview, uiview

Its common to observe listview developments for webforms but no common in mvc. on the other hand for mvc I´m only finding grid views displaying tabular data.

In your opinion which is the best List view solution for asp.net mvc?.

Edited:
ok, finally I found a possibility. Kazi Manzur wrote a listview using telerik controls. http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/03/24/creating-rich-view-components-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: what are you trying to do? Output data in some type of ListView using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Hi hunter... yes, and I only can find tabular data display using grid views. I search a lot on the internet and with no success

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MVC you usually just create a loop and write the list yourself.

```
<ul>
@foreach (var message in Model.Messages)
{
    <li>@message</li>
} 
</ul>
```

This programming model gives you more control and fits MVC much better so I don't think there is a need for something like the webforms listview.

UPDATE: Adding pagingsupport is quite easy with a HtmlHelper. See http://rickyrosario.com/blog/simple-htmlhelper-extension-for-paging-in-asp-net-mvc/ 
Look at the pages linked from the post too.

Comment: hi mikael, thank you for your support. of course a loop would be the approach but I cannot find an important support for other areas on a list view such as integrated and custom paging, or multicolumn and custom sorting as examples..

Comment: Added a link to a post about paging. I haven't seen any generic solution sorting though

Comment: +1 Start simple, don't start with a heavy feature dense component with server side dependencies. I'm a huge fan of simple, fast, lightweight markup.

Comment: Isn't this accessing Model from View which is a bad practice?

Comment: Accessing the Model or ViewModel from the View is NOT a bad practice. That is how you build MVC applications. The Controller feeds the View with a Model and the View renders that Model. The Views only responsibility is to render the HTML/GUI for a certain Model.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that ASP.NET MVC puts the power of HTML in your hands. This opens up access to a variety of open source widget libraries.

- JQuery UI
- ExtJS (Sencha)
- MooTools

You will be ultimately be responsible for creating the HTML, but a lot of these libraries offer guidance as to what that HTML will look like.

Comment: Hi Khalid, thank you for your answer. Yes, if found many approaches but no one comprises at the moment a list view solution ready to be played on mvc. I was very surprised taking into consideration that mostly all websites display listviews for their offerings and not tabular data style. but i cannot find something like @listview. in the same way webgrid or similar works. I was surprised about that...

Comment: Are you utilizing MVC3. There is an Grid helper in MVC three that keeps you from having to write a lot of HTML if you don't want to. There is also one in MVCContrib. My issue with these are they breakdown after complex UI scenarios and routing scenarios for paging.

Comment: yes, I´m using mvc3 and checked webgrid but its still tabular data (header, rows, columns). brgds

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Grid plugin is pretty good: http://www.trirand.com/blog/.  It requires you to write the table yourself, but then gives you lots of power for paging/sorting, etc...

MVCContrib has a grid component that is real slick and might be more what you are use to coming from a webforms background: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com

Microsoft is also working on a grid jQuery plugin, but I think that is still a ways off.

Comment: Hi Ely, thank you so much. Based on my experience all grid solutions for mvc request to have a header, one data per column etc... listview gives you much more customization possibilities and I cannot find a plug an play solution for mvc in that area...

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood and thought you were looking for a grid.  The jQuery UI library might have something that would help: http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 1):

The examples of using a ListView that I have seen also add in jQuery [Tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). [This post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PageSortMVCinCsharp03192009083337AM/PageSortMVCinCsharp.aspx) shows an example of using  with jQuery to get both sorting and paging support.

And here's another post showing the user of the Listview with the jQuery Tablesorter plugin: http://beckelman.net/post/2008/10/16/Client-Side-ASPNET-ListView-Sorting-via-jQuery-TableSorter-Plugin-Demo.aspx